# how to make an input field display a .txt file

Tags: html, forms

I want to know if I can show my .txt file in a form input field. (kind of like how you can refrence it with an iframe)

```html
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
  <!--<input name="field1" type="text" src ="user.txt" /> I already tried this-->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit feedback">
</form>
```

Comment: You just literally want to show the contents of the txt file as the value in the input?

Comment: I think you should use a textarea for the display and a database to store the text

Comment: Do you mean a local file (on the user's computer) or a remote one (on the server)?

Comment: i mean a file on the server srry

Comment: also yes ot amorrisees question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to do this with HTML only.**

You could load the txt file with Ajax (something [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) and then replace the value of the text field with the content of the file once the Ajax request is completed. **I would not recommend this**, though.

An much better approach would be to just read the file in backend using some other backend language.

If you used PHP, your code would look something like this :

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('./user.txt'); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit feedback">
</form>
```

Comment: @parseguy : I'm getting a 403 error when I click that link. What did you do?

Comment: oh sorry but the main idea of the photo was that the input field was only displaying the literal words <?php echo file_get_contents('./user.txt'); ?>

Comment: Sorry, I hate url shorteners they always expire after a while

Comment: @parseguy : For this code to work, you should (1) make sure your server supports PHP and (2) rename your file from eg. `index.html` to `index.php`.

Comment: does php support forms?

Comment: @parseguy : The output of your PHP should be just normal HTML. So if something is supported by HTML, it's supported by PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php.

Comment: Dear Mr slegers, this works, it displays the text but then the php dosen't work. here is what I have: http://hokuco.com/Home/services/feedback.zip Can you help

Comment: @parseguy : Are you sure you have PHP installed on your server?

Comment: im sure if not then this example wouldnt work http://hokuco.com/Home/services/feed.html you may notice that this is the example I wanted to alter in this question.

Comment: btw the data is stored in user.txt

Comment: @parseguy : You need to do two things : (1) Rename `feed.html` to `feed.php` and (2) replace your input element with `<input name="field1" type="text" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('./user.txt'); ?>" />`. Once you did that, (1) upload everything to your server again and (2) run http://hokuco.com/Home/services/feed.php.